# Коллизии в играх. Как определить сторону, которой один квадрат столкнулся с другим?

Tags: javascript, html5, разработка-игр

Пишу игру на js (платформер). Игрок представлен в виде квадрата, тайлы карты - тоже квадраты. На каждом кадре определяю, есть ли факт столкновения игрока с каким либо из ближайших тайлов:

```
if (a.position.x <= b.position.x + b.width &&
    a.position.x + a.width >= b.position.x &&
    a.position.y <= b.position.y + b.height &&
    a.height + a.position.y >= b.position.y) {
    console.log('Collision!');
}
```

Таким образом я определяю, есть ли столкновение вообще, но как определить, если столкновение произошло, то какой именно стороной игрок столкнулся с тайлом? Учитывая, что это тривиальная задача при разработке игр, наверняка есть какой-то классический алгоритм для ее решения. Какой он?

Comment: Можно ли узнать для чего вам необходимо знать какой стороной столкнулся? И забегая вперед скажу, что в платформерах 2D как правило определяют сторону, в которую по дефолту смотрит игрок `facingRight = true;` а потом при повороте игрока, меняют данную переменную

Comment: Мне нужно это знать, для нескольких целей. Например, чтобы понять - запрыгнул игрок на платформу или нет. Если он прикоснулся к ней правой стороной, значит нет, если нижней - значит да. Второй пример - враги. Если игрок прикоснулся к врагу нижней стороной, враг умирает, если любой другой, умирает сам игрок (как в марио). За информацию про дефолтное направление игрока спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Вычислите координаты центра каждого квадрата, затем разницу

```
var acenter = { x: a.position.x + a.width / 2, y: a.position.y + a.height / 2 };
var bcenter = { x: b.position.x + b.width / 2, y: b.position.y + b.height / 2 };
var d = { x: acenter.x - bcenter.x, y: acenter.y - bcenter.y };
```

Тогда в d у вас будет направление от одного квадрата к другому. Например если d.x больше нуля, то один квадрат правее другого. Или по тангенсу угол посчитать можно.

Comment: Но как быть с тем, что квадрат может прикасаться к другому квадрату только одной стороной а значений получается два (d.x и d.y)? Квадрат ведь не может столкнуться с другим квадратом и нижней и правой стороной одновременно.

Comment: Квадрат может столкнуться по диагонали. Например квадрат сдвинулся на (1,1) и стал соприкасатся с другим в одном пикселе в вершине. Это ни сверху ни слева, а по диагонали. В зависимости от вашей физики соприконтуся можно много или мало. Если такого быть не может то возьмите максимальное по модулю значение и посмотрите оно больше или меньше нуля. Так останется 4 варианта.

Comment: Можно чуть подробнее про этот способ? Что вы имеете ввиду, когда говорите, что прикоснуться можно много или мало? Глубину проникновения?

Comment: http://imgur.com/zx1HpAP - вот тут с какой стороны какие квадраты пересекаются? Сверху? Снизу?

Comment: Синий нижней стороной, красный либо нижней, либо правой, зеленый либо верхней, либо левой

Comment: Ну вот раз "либо либо" то смотрите на знак максимального по модулю значения в дельте. Так вы получите одно из направлений, самое "значительное".